# Error in DynamicDatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase connection string parsing

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012-express

I'm not very familiar with DynamicDatabaseFactory and there isn't a lot of information out there.  I'm making changes to a site and I'm just trying to get it to run on my development machine and I've run into this problem, the line: `DynamicDatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(MyConnectionString, DBProviderType.SqlServer)` generates this error: `[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.`.  I know the connection string is good because it is used in other areas of the application and connects to the database with no problem. In the debugger I can see that the string is being provided properly.  So what am I missing?

Comment: What is `DynamicDatabaseFactory` in this context? Is it one of your custom classes or a library from somewhere?

Comment: It's a library, EnterpriseLibrary.Extensions.Data.DynamicDatabaseFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using one of the overloads to the `CreateDatabase` method:

```
Static db As Database = DynamicDatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("localhost\SQLEXPRESS", "MYDB", "username", "password", DBProviderType.SqlServer)
```

This overload allows you to pass the server, database, username and password to the method instead of passing just the connection string.  I suspect, but cannot confirm, that the call coded earlier was having a problem parsing the server portion of the connection string, I use Sql Express in my development environment and the database is located at `"localhost/SQLEXPRESS"`, production uses the full version of Sql Server which is located at `"localhost"`.  In any event, I was able to get things working with the line of code above.